# Double-Chained Kama and Kama profiency and use questions

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

This is technically a two part question.  For the sake of this question assume that the PC is *not* a Monk or already proficient with "all Monk weapons" by some other means.

Description of the Double-Chained Kama from d20pfsrd for reference:

> The wielder can attack as if armed with a single kama in each hand or extend the chain to make a single reach attack. By swinging the rope, the wielder can whip the kama about to disarm or trip opponents. Furthermore, if one of the weapons is dropped, the wielder can retrieve as a free action by pulling on the chain.

1. If you are somehow proficient with the Double-Chained Kama (ie EWP feat or Weapon Familiarity custom race trait), are you considered proficient with Kamas when using each side as a single Kama?
2. If you are proficient with the Double-Chained Kama, are you considered proficient with the single Kama as well?

Note: Both are Exotic weapons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, the creature makes attacks as if proficient with the single kamas used in each hand, but only because they're not *actual* kamas but *as if* they were kamas. The double-chained kama remains a double-chained kama no matter how it's used.
2. No. Proficiency with the double-chained kama doesn't grant proficiency with the kama.

---

The [double-chained kama](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/kama-double-chained) says that

> The wielder can attack ***as if*** armed with a single kama in each hand or extend the chain to make a single reach attack. By swinging the rope, the wielder can whip the kama about to disarm or trip opponents. Furthermore, if one of the weapons is dropped, the wielder can retrieve as a free action by pulling on the chain.

When a creature possesses the feat [Exotic Weapon Proficiency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/exotic-weapon-proficiency-combat---final) (double-chained kama), this gives him no other proficiency with others weapons. Luckily, the emphasis-mine *as if* saves the character from even needing Exotic Weapon Proficiency ([kama](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/kama)), allowing the user to attack with a weapon that's like a kama but, which, in fact, is a *double-chained* kama.